# Get index of an item within mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a query which looks like:

```
function getPage(page) {
  return db.messages.aggregate(
    {
      '$group': {
        _id: "$subjectID"
      }
    },
    { '$skip': page * 20 },
    { '$limit' : 20 });
}
```

Say I have a `subjectID` that I know appears somewhere in that collection.  What I want to do is write something like:

```
function pageOf(subjectID) {
  return Math.floor(db.messages.aggregate(
    {
      '$group': {
        _id: "$subjectID"
      }
    }).indexOf({__id: subjectID}) / 20);
}
```

Except I have no idea how to write the `indexOf` part of that query.  I was wondering if mongodb might have some sort of "take while" or "take until" query, then you could do that followed by a count of the number of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ordering by subjectID

If your `subjectID` is (or can be changed to) a monotonically increasing value (for example, a MongoDB default ObjectID), you have a straightforward option using a normal `find()` with appropriate sort, skip, and limit. In this case you can look for documents with subjectIDs [`$gte` (greater than or equal to)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gte/) your `subjectID`:

```
var page = 1;
var subjectID = ObjectId("515535a0760fe8735f5f6897");
db.users.find(
    { _id: { $gte : subjectID } }
).sort({'_id':1}).skip(page*20).limit(20)
```

#### Aggregation Framework

As at MongoDb 2.4, there is no such feature in the Aggregation Framework to match based on the document position in the result pipeline.  You could file a new feature suggestion the MongoDB Jira project's [SERVER](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) queue.

It sounds like you would want a new pipeline operator such as a `$matchfrom` which would ignore any documents until the first occurrence of the `$matchfrom` criteria.  You could then add a `$limit` to take the next n items.  You would also want to have sorted output before the `$matchfrom` so there is a predictable outcome.

This seems overcomplicated compared to having an increasing subjectID, but there may be a use case for doing paging based on more advanced search criteria or results calculated in the aggregation pipeline.

#### Alternative approaches

Aside from future support for such a feature in the Aggregation Framework, you have a few options to implement the same matching approach in code:

- use the older [`group()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/) aggregation command with a `finalize()` function.  NOTE: `group()` does **not** work with sharded clusters.
- use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) and a `finalize()` function
- fetch the whole result set from the Aggregation Framework, and implement the matching/reduction of results in your application code (though this somewhat defeats the "paging" notion if you are fetching all pages for every request).

#### Performance considerations

Queries with `skip` still have to read through the intervening index entries, so skipping a large number of documents will not be very efficient.

Instead of paging with a skip offset, you could consider doing successive page queries by starting from the last entry of the previous page (i.e. the first page would be `$gte` the starting subjectID and subsequent pages would be `$gt` the last subjectID included on the previous page).  This will depend on how you present the paging in your user interface - it would be easiest to use this approach if your UI only has the option to show "next" page of messages rather than jumping to a specific page.

Comment: The ordering thing is a really good idea.  Unfortunately I can't use gt/gte for my pagination because my page urls are of the form `/<page-number>` and I want to stick with that.  I have about 26000 items and use a `$group` operation to produce about 20000 groups.  I'm adding about 15-20 items per day and it's still performing fine at the moment.  I'm making a fair bit of use of caching and query times of up to about 1 second are still acceptable.

Comment: *to produce about 2000 groups