# Retrieve index of item in array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, mongoid3

similar to

-[Aggregation: add option to $unwind to emit array index](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588)

-[Get index of an item within mongodb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975900/get-index-of-an-item-within-mongodb-query)

I have this use case.

Tastiest Fruit Rankings:

```
{"date": "Jan 1st",
"fruit_ranking": ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Pear"]},
{"date": "Jan 2nd",
"fruit_ranking": ["Orange", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Pear", "Apple"]}
.....
{"date": "Dec 31st",
"fruit_ranking":  ["Kiwi", "Apple", "Grape", "Mango", "Pear"]}
```

I'm trying to grab the ranking of "Pear" for each day Jan 1st - Dec 31st and right now I need to grab all of the arrays back and do indexOf 
in my application.  Would speed up my application quite a bit if theres some way of doing this in MongoDB and just return the index of "Pear" instead of the whole Array.

I looked into [Map Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) but the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) seem to suggest you need to have a reduce function which doesn't work.

Also looked in to [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) but this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588) ticket seems to suggest its not implemented yet.

Lastly, I looked into [Server Side Scripting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) but it seems too advanced for a simple use case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this code, but it should work.

Presuming the db name where this is stored in is `tastyFruits`...

```
tastyFruits.find({}).forEach(function(a){
console.log("Date: " + a.date);
console.log("Pear rating: " + a.fruit_ranking.indexOf("Pear"));
});
```

Comment: Interesting concept.  Unfortunately that only logs the indexes in the MongoDB logs but doesn't actually return the indexes.  ps.  its print() and not console.log()

Comment: If you want to return the indexes, simply push those pear ratings to an array and return the array. Not sure what language you're using, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  Its a little bit sketchy because of injection problems but it works and its super fast.

Comment: hi mjkaufer,  would you mind changing your answer to print instead of console.log for future clarity?